# Dynamically appending SVG content using React dangerouslySetInnerHTML with filter is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to dynamically adding SVG content in react for displaying my logo.

The logo SVG paths are being stored in the database and being passed to the ui.

This is the way I'm doing this in my react component:

```js
const createLanguageListItemIcon = function(language) {
  const svgFilterDef = `
    <defs>
      <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
        <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix"
        values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="1" />
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
  `;

  return (
    <ListItemIcon>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgFilterDef + language.logo_svg }}/>
    </ListItemIcon>
  );
}
```

The icon is being displayed in both **Chrome** and **Firefox**, but the shadow only works in **Firefox**. btw if I dump the `svgFilterDef + language.logo_svg` in console and copy paste it directly in an empty basic html file the shadow works in **Chrome** too. Does anyone know what is the issue here?

Are there any other ways to create shadows for **SVG paths** in web?

Comment: Can you post the output of this component? Does logo.svg have its own `<svg>` tag?

Comment: If you just want a shadow you could use the [css drop-shadow filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow).

Comment: Thank you. @rayhatfield there are no logo.svg files. but the language.logo_svg doesn't have the svg tag around it. The problem for drop-shadow css property is that, it's not being supported for Paths on Chrome.

Comment: I found the issue. the problem is the drop-shadow css property. I had set that for my paths on css and it wasn't working for chrome. but then seems that if that property exists, Chrome won't apply the filter. The other thing is that the shadow I was seeing on Firefox, it was actually because of drop-shadow.